Why am I getting this error " Vector memory exhausted" nothing has changed except volume of lines of code
library(tidyverse)

Sys.setenv("VROOM_CONNECTION_SIZE" = 262144)

# Read the CSV files into separate data frames
df1 <- Combined_Activity_and_Follow
df2 <- Combined_Activity_and_Follow_2
df3 <- Combined_Activity_and_Follow_4

combined_df <- bind_rows(df1, df2, df3)
FollowData<-combined_df 

Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)
I don't under stand why all of a sudden this code isn't working.
I have another 1930 lines of code to add in dates for each specific follow and other dates .
it was working fine yesterday but now the FollowData object has vanished and won't create anew.
Can I fix it?
I am using a 2023 MacBook Pro.
Context the three Drs are made from importing data from 3 CSV files
I have underneath code to clean and tidy it up.
I have tried opening a new project, new r script turning it off and on again.
I am relatively beginner at R.
